# Listen for custom protocol in a java application

Tags: java, protocols

I have created a java app and I would like to be able to execute actions in this app by calling some custom urls (ex: myapp://do_this)

I have already searched for this, and I have found some information about handling such urls in java (URLStreamHandler).

The only part I'm missing, is how to tell the OS to redirect the "myapp://" protocol to my application.

More and more apps are defining their own protocol and I was wondering whether it was possible to create such kind of things in Java.

Thanks

Comment: how do you think a browser will understand myapp://??

Comment: The same way a browser understands file://, ftp://, apt://, itunes:// and a bunch of custom protocols defined by other apps. So I suppose their is a way to add new protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol in URLStreamHandler will be used inside of the jvm. Typical usage is something like res://... for resources. The OS and the browsers have their own sets of protocols (ftp, mailto).

You could probably extend Firefox with a plugin to handle your protocol.

But then you have to send that to your app, running as a small "web" server.

Forget for a moment URLStreamHandler.

Embed the Jetty web server in your app, say on port 8765, and write a servlet to handle your URLs. Then you can in your browser type "http://localhost:8765/do_this". Should suffice.

Comment: Yes, that could be the easiest actually... and would be really independent from the browser, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add a new protocol, one needs to implement an XPCOM component. Since XPCOM allows programming languages to talk to eachother, XPCOM components can be implemented in C++ or JavaScript currently in Mozilla.

http://www.nexgenmedia.net/docs/protocol/ will help you to understand more.

i think this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is an example of what I'm trying to do, but I would prefer something os/browser independent as my application runs on multiple os.

Comment: In that case, i'm afraid you might have to standardize your protocols, such that they are packed in next versions of browsers :P

Comment: Well, apparently, it is possible to add new protocols via AppleScript on Mac, via the registry on Windows... So I thought maybe there is a java lib that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, getting browsers to understand a new protocol name is browser (and OS) specific - you can't do it from the server.

However, would Java Web Start ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/ ) fit your requirements? Most browsers are already set up to handle JWS applications correctly.

Comment: No, it's a desktop application but I would like to easily allow other apps or links in a webpage to do actions in the software.